# Is there a programmatic way to update an android app on the android market?

Tags: android, google-play

Are there any web service APIs available that allow the developer to upload a new build of their android app without having to manually use the android market developer GUI?  I would like to configure my one click build system to also deploy to the market if possible.

Comment: I've never run across an API that does this. Which I think is probably good, providing such a mechanism would almost surely lead to more spam on the Market. If you want to automate the process your best bet is probably working around the web front end that already exists and trying to use some kind of macro program to input all of the relavent data for you.

Comment: I don't think an API would affect spam on the Market if it were limited to updating existing apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could automate this e.g. with a recorded and parameterized selenium script.

Answer (score 0):

This capability doesn't exist currently.